# How to clear OSX cached applications?

Tags: macos, applications, software-update

I'm having a very strange bug with an application. I've tried to update it but it keeps showing up the old version. I've tried deleting it too, but when I run `open -a MyApplication.app` it opens it again, even though I'm sure it's not anywhere. If after that I try to install again the new version, it's still showing the old one.

So I assume OSX is caching it somewhere. Does anybody know where this cache is or how to clear it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue once. I solved it by running [AppFresh](http://metaquark.de/appfresh/mac) and scan to check if all apps are updated. When you find the one that gives you trouble, you can right-click and choose Reveal in Finder, and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

As to where it is...

The few times I used Time Machine it would find multiple copies of apps, upon closer inspection those apps were on the Time Machine volume. Do you have one of those hooked up?